# How to get the address of a static template method from a class that is passed as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to get the address of a static method from a class that is passed as a template argument to another class. Below is a pared down example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

typedef size_t Data;

class MyFunction
{
private:
    static const std::array<std::string, 3> values;

public:
    template<size_t N>
    static void Func(const Data& aData)
    {
        size_t index = (N > aData ? 2 : (N == aData ? 1 : 0) );
        cout << "Function::Func<"<< N << ">:\t" << N << values[index] << aData << endl;
    }

    typedef decltype(&Func<0>) type;    
};

const std::array<std::string, 3> MyFunction::values {"<", "=", ">"};

template<class Function, size_t N>
class FunctionManager
{
private:
    static const typename Function::type func_;

    static constexpr typename Function::type Create()
    {
        return &Function::Func<N>; //ERROR: Causes "overloaded function with no contextual information".
    }
public: 
    void operator()(const Data &aData) const
    {
        func_(aData);
    }
};

template<class Function, size_t N>
const typename Function::type FunctionManager<Function, N>::func_ = FunctionManager<Function, N>::Create();

int main()
{
    static const size_t N = 6;
    auto man = FunctionManager<MyFunction, N>();
    man(N/2);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also find the code [here](http://ideone.com/52xx1m). The problem is in the Create() function, I get "address of overloaded function with no contextual type information" error. However, if I change &Function::Func to &MyFunction::Func, it works fine. I would like to make the actual function a template parameter and not hard-code it, anyone have any idea how to fix this problem? Note that I realize there are simpler ways of doing what I'm trying to do, but the actual code instead of a single Function::type creates an array of them using the index trick, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `&Function::template Func<N>` - the compiler doesn't know that you have a template there and expects a value by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Smells a bit like XY problem, could you elaborate more about purpose of your `Create()` function, and why you don't want to 'hardcode' the concrete function's reference? How do you intend clients using this interface? Arbitrarily selecting from their static methods to pass one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message causes some head scratching, indeed. Here's what's missing:

```
return &Function::template Func<N>;
//                ^^^^^^^^
```

`Function` is a template parameter and you need to help the compiler and tell it that the nested name `Func` names a template.